# libGDX Mouse over on UI element fires same event from underlying Actor

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx, mouseevent, scene2d

I'm making a simple RTS game. I've created separate Stages for map and UI, and used scene2D Table class for side panel. The problem is, when i hover my side panel, if there is an actor (building) under panel at the moment, it fires its mouseover event.  Click events work properly.

Here is my building class input listeners:

```
    public class Building extends Actor {

    addListener(new InputListener(){
                        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                        System.out.println("Click");
                           return true;
                        }
                        public  void    enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor){
                            ((Building)event.getTarget()).hover = true;
                        }
```

Here is my panel class listeners

```
public class SidePanel extends Table {
        panelBg = new Image(skin,"side-panel");
        addListener(new InputListener(){
            public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                System.out.println("Click");
                return true;
            }
            public  void    enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor){
System.out.println("Enter");
            }
        });
          addActor(panelBg);
              }
    }
```

Then side panel is added to UI class stage:

```
public class UI {
    public  UI(){
        stage = new Stage();
        sidePanel = new SidePanel();
        stage.addActor(sidePanel);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
      }
```

And finally i added UI to main class:

```
    @Override
    public void create () {
        ui = new UI();
        CP =new InputMultiplexer();
        CP.addProcessor(ui.stage);
        CP.addProcessor(gameStage);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(CP);
    }
```

Not sure where the problem is, because click event works fine;

Comment: Please include a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that still shows this same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick solution would be to have your Building class check if the mouse was also over the SidePanel. For example, you could change your Building listener's `enter` method to something like this:

```
if (mouseIsOverSidePanel)
    ((Building)event.getTarget()).hover = true;
```

Your SidePanel listener's `enter` method can be something like this:

```
mouseIsOverSidePanel = true;
```

And your `leave` method in your SidePanel can be:

```
mouseIsOverSidePanel = false;
```

This is mostly pseudo code so it won't work without declaring the variables (obviously) but it should give you a basic idea of how to fix your problem.

Comment: Yeah, it works. (It seems pretty obvious though, how happened i didn't figure it myself :( ) 
Many thanks